# API gateway for WebSocket + OAuth

Tags: oauth, websocket

Is there websocket api gateway in .net core?
More accurately, i'm looking for gateway which can proxying websockets and supports oauth authentication, it means in moment of websocket's http initial handshake gateway should check headers of http request and validate oauth token, if not - redirect to login page.

Maybe i'm thinking in the wrong way about oauth with websockets, the main purpose is to validate and login user before he get access to services.

I didn't find websocket gateway in .net core, but haProxy supports websockets, maybe there is a way to oauth authentication into it.